# How to display the whole web app inside a html element

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create a layout like this :

[Example layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bTux.png)

I want to display the whole page in that black element, How to do this with html and css.
It has scrollabe content, and the content should stay within that black element.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `iframe` html elements for solve your problem.

example:

```
 <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com" width="1000" height="1000">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     <div class="block">
        <p class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
 

    .block {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
```